# I want to validate years or month input feild

Tags: jquery

I want to validate years or month. When I enter any value like year or month then my step is going forward. I just want to validate here when I enter a value year then it will run or when I enter month then it will run.

**My HTML Code**

```html
<fieldset class="steps step7 au_cr_feild" name="stp_receive_period">
    <h2 class="au-cr-title">How Long Have You Been <br>Receiving This Monthly Income?</h2>
        <div class="line-divider"></div>

        <div class="input-label">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="0" name="Years_At_Employer" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
            <span>Years</span>
        </div>

        <div class="input-label">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="0" name="Months_At_Employer" aria-required="true"
                class="valid" aria-describedby="Months_At_Employer-error" aria-invalid="false">
            <span>Months</span>
        </div>
```

**Here Is My jquery Code**

```js
if (stp_name == "stp_receive_period") {
  $.validator.addMethod("Years_At_Employer", function(value, element) {
     if (value >= 1)
    return true;
  }, "Minimum 1 Years to apply");

   //validation setting for receiving period
    settings = {
     ignore: [],
     rules: {
     "Years_At_Employer": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                Years_At_Employer: true
            },
            "Months_At_Employer": {
                //required: true,
                number: true,
                //Months_At_Employer: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            "Years_At_Employer": {
                required: "Please input number of years",
                number: "Number of years should be a number value"
            },
            "Months_At_Employer": {
                //required: "Please input number of months",
                number: "Number of months should be a number value"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo($("[name=" + stp_name + "]").find(".error_msg"));

        }
    };
}
```

**Here Is My Frontend**

[image]

Comment: is it ok to use input type as number. `<input type="number" max="12" min="0" placeholder="0" name="Months_At_Employer" ...`

Comment: thank you for your response but when I enter the value of year then it works but when I enter month then got an error that, please enter month I want to validate both if the year is entered then work or if I entered month without year then should work but it's not working if I use only month.

Comment: Basically, I Want if both are empty then get an error otherwise if one field is filled up(year or month) then it should work